# "you" with a capital letter

Tags: meaning-in-context, capitalization

After the death of the Queen, I wrote:

> I am feeling blue without You.

Immediately, I got a word of criticism on the use of capital "y". Well, I was, sort of, addressing a monarch, and couldn't say Your Majesty, as it would destroy the rhyme. Was it a real mistake?

Comment: You may use a capital _You_ when speaking to anyone who is not physically present in the world. All gods, saints, gurus, and dead people generally are included.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your capitalization is indeed incorrect.  You is never capitalized except at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: Actually, pronouns were traditionally capitalised when addressing God (but not a monarch!).

Comment: So why do we capitalize Your Majesty? Shouldn't it be your Majesty/majesty then?

Comment: You and your are two similar, but different, words.

Comment: If you said "Your Majesty" is a title and therefore capitalised. I would believe and thank you. This answer of yours doesn't explain anything, sorry.